# Ambiguous use of operator '!='?

Tags: function, swift, if-statement, uibutton, ibaction

I am trying to create an if else statement. If the randomNumber equals the text of a label, then I want to add 1 to the `CorrectLabel`. If they do not equal each other than I want to add 1 to the `IncorrectLabel`. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func checkButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if ( "\(randomImageGeneratorNumber)" == "\(currentCountLabel.text)"){
        currectAmountCorrect += 1
        CorrectLabel.text = "\(currectAmountCorrect)"

    }else if ("\(randomImageGeneratorNumber)" != "\(currentCountLabel.text)"){
        currentAmountIncorrect += 1
        IncorrectLabel.text = "\(currentAmountIncorrect)"
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the "else if" statement line saying "Ambiguous use of operator '!=' ". I am unsure of what this error means or how to fix it.

What does this error mean and how can it be fixed?

Comment: If both sides (lhs & rhs) are strings, then this issue have been fixed in Swift 1.2 (just tried it). In the meantime you could just do `if !(lhs == rhs)` instead (or just an `else` since your first criterion is just an equality test and hence an inequality would be implied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't compare like that. Just use `.toInt()` to cast the labeltext to int and compare it like that:

```
var currentCount = currentCountLabel.text?.toInt()
if randomImageGeneratorNumber == currentCount {
    currectAmountCorrect += 1
    CorrectLabel.text = "\(currectAmountCorrect)"

} else {
    currentAmountIncorrect += 1
    IncorrectLabel.text = "\(currentAmountIncorrect)"
}
```

There is no need to put your value into a "".

Comment: When I switch out my code with yours, an error comes up saying "String? does not have a member named 'toInt'. What does this mean and how do I fix it.

Comment: I've edited the code. You need to unwrap the text first

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to make comparison twice. Your code looks like

```
if true {
...
} else if false {
...
}
```

And, yes, int comparison would be better:

```
if let textAmount = currentCountLabel.text where randomImageGeneratorNumber == textAmount.toInt() {
    currectAmountCorrect += 1
    CorrectLabel.text = "\(currectAmountCorrect)"
} else {
    currentAmountIncorrect += 1
    IncorrectLabel.text = "\(currentAmountIncorrect)"
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and an error came up on the `currentAmountCorrect += 1` line of code saying `"Swift Compiler Error: Will never be executed"` but I combined the top of your answer with the bottom.